# Bootstrap navbar-scrolled - Links not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have problem with my mobile menu. It is working well, but when i scroll (with sticky header) the menu will be blurry grey and the links are not available anymore. I can't find the issue. Maybe someone can help me out.

there comes a "navbar-active" into my class and deactivate or make it blurry the hole mobile menu.

```
.site-navbar.navbar-scrolled {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 22px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1030;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Debugging a live site is not really the thing around here. The question should be something that will also be useful to someone else in the future. (Who knows what will happen to that site.) If you could make a minimal demo, you'll have a better chance of getting help.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes i understand this. Demo i can not provide. But i add.. that it is a standard class (which will be added when you start scrolling) with the name navbar-active.

Comment: Try changing the z-index to 1050, so it will be higher than the `body-backdrop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `body-backdrop` has a z-index of 1040.
So changing the menu to 1050, fixes the problem.

```css
.site-navbar.navbar-scrolled {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 22px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1050;
  top: 0;
}
```